# Tailwind-Styled-Component Npm Package TypeScript Error. How can i solve this Error

Tags: typescript, next.js, styled-components

module.style.ts  file

```
import tw from "tailwind-styled-components";

export const Container = tw.div`
 bg-blue-600
`;

export const Button = tw.button`
 p-2
`;
```

index.tsx file

```
import React from "react";
import { Button, Container } from "./module.navbarStyles";

type Props = {};

const index = (props: Props) => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Button>Hello Next.js</Button>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default index;
```

Then I got this type of Error.

> Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.ts(2589).

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yBnU.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
export const Container = tw.div<any>`
 bg-blue-600
`;

export const Button = tw.button<any>`
 p-2
`;
```

For more info check https://github.com/pmndrs/react-spring/issues/1515#issuecomment-948381296

Also here if you want to keep track of the issue https://github.com/MathiasGilson/Tailwind-Styled-Component/issues/79

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).